# Laravel 4: Using flexible layouts within routes

Tags: php, routes, laravel, laravel-4, template-engine

I have an application without controllers and read about [controller layouts](http://laravel.com/docs/templates#controller-layouts) in [laravel 4 documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/templates) and [this other article too](http://jasonlewis.me/article/laravel-controller-and-route-layouts), but I don't know where to start for implement it within routes (version 4), how can I do that?

*Error received: InvalidArgumentException, View [master] not found.*

### app/routes.php

```
<?php
View::name('layouts.master', 'layout');
$layout = View::of('layout');
Route::get('users/create', array('as' => 'users.create', function() use($layout) {
  //@TODO: load view using 'layouts.master',
  //       desirable: append 'users.create' and 'users.menu' views to sidebar and content sections.
  //return View::make('users.create');
  return $layout->nest('content', 'master');
  }));
?>
```

### app/views/layouts/master.blade.php

```
<html>
  <body>
    @section('sidebar')
      This is the master sidebar.
    @show

    <div class="container">
      @yield('content')
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

### app/views/users/create.blade.php

```
{{ Form::open() }}

{{ Form::text('name') }}
{{ Form::submit('submit') }}

{{ Form::close() }}
```

### app/views/users/menu.blade.php

```
<!-- This is appended to the master sidebar -->
<p><a href="users/create">Create user</a></p>
```

***Update**: I modified example code to clarify what I want to do. Check `app/routes.php` and its comments*

Comment: 'without blade code...' means for the views; I firmly believe someone knows how to load it all.

Comment: `return $layout->nest('content', 'master');` is wrong, it should be `return $layout->nest('content', 'layouts.master');`

Comment: @HalfCrazed Thank you, I was missing the "return" in there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code in your routes file is trying to nest the master layout within itself, which isn't really what you want. You're getting the error because `'master'` would look for `app/views/master.blade.php`. That's easily fixed by changing it to `'layouts.master'`, but I wouldn't like to think what might happen...

The root cause of the issue you're having is the difference between "yielding" views from a Blade template, and nesting them from a route. When you nest a route, you need to `echo` it rather than using the `@yield` tag.

```php
// File: app/routes.php

View::name('layouts.master', 'layout');
$layout = View::of('layout');

Route::get('users/create', array('as' => 'users.create', function() use ($layout)
{
    return $layout
            ->nest('content', 'users.create')
            ->nest('sidebar', 'users.menu');
}));


/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| View Composer
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Code in this method will be applied to all views that use the master
| layout. We use that to our advantage by injecting an "empty" sidebar
| when none is set when returning the view. It will error otherwise.
|
*/

View::composer('layouts.master', function($view)
{
    if (!array_key_exists('sidebar', $view->getData()))
    {
        $view->with('sidebar', '');
    }
});


// File: app/views/layouts/master.blade.php

<html>
<body>
    @section('sidebar')
        This is the master sidebar
        {{ $sidebar }}
    @show

    <div class="container">
        {{ $content }}
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Laravel's [View composers](http://laravel.com/docs/responses#view-composers) are a powerful tool. If you have any data (eg logged-in user info) used by all views that share the same template(s), you can use the composers to save injecting the data every time you load the view.

Comment: I didn't expect use `echo` but it works! Thanks Dave. And sorry for the delay, I have an injury in my forearms.

Comment: Alternately to using the view composer for sidebar, you can use
    {{ $sidebar or '' }}

Answer (score 0):

You could also use the @parent tag to append content, assuming you;re using blade for templating. E.g. (in the view)

```
@section('sidebar')
    @parent
    <p>This is appended to the master sidebar.</p>
@stop
```

Comment: "I prefer not use blade code" but I had to use it; all views will be coded by common people (HTML code is enough).

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use nesting views if you're using blade.

### app/views/users/create.blade.php

You need to extend the `master.blade`

```
@extends('layouts.master')
@section('content')
// form stuff here
@stop
```

Now, all you need to do is call `create.blade`

`return View::make('users.create')`

Comment: Does this work in routes.php ? its quite easy to use layouts in controllers but when it comes to routes it becomes messy..

Answer (score 0):

Just throwing this out there as a possible solution using controller routing (whereas you can set the template from within the controller).

app/routes.php

```
Route::controller('something', 'SomethingController');
```

app/controllers/SomethingController.php

```
class SomethingController extends BaseController {
  protected $layout = "templates.main"; // denotes views/templates/main.blade.php

  public function getIndex() { // the "landing" page for "/something" or "/something/index"
    $this->layout->content = View::make('something.index')->with("myVar", "Hello, world!"); // load in views/something/index.blade.php INTO main.blade.php
  }

  public function getTest() { // for "/something/test"
    $this->layout->content = View::make('something.index')->nest("widget", "something.widget", array("myVar" => "Hello, World!"));
  }
}
```

app/views/templates/main.blade.php

```
@include('templates.partials.header')
@yield('something')
@yield('content')
@include('templates.partials.footer')
```

app/views/something/widget.blade.php

```
I'm a widget. {{ $myVar }}
```

app/views/something/index.blade.php

```
@section('something')
  I will go in the 'something' yield in main.blade.php
@stop

@section('content')
  I will go in the 'content' yield in main.blade.php.

  {{ $myVar }}

  {{ $widget }}
@stop

?>
```

Now you can test `http://myserver/something` and `http://myserver/something/test` to see the differences. Note: not tested but as a rough example.